# How to handle 2 radio buttons per search result with php

Tags: php, html, forms, controller, radio-button

When my user searches for game in my DB, I present them with a list of the games that match their search term, and then i want to add a button to each item that allows the user to select "have it" or "want it" then have a single "add" button that adds their selections to their profile.

because you cant have it and want it at the same time, i assumed a radio button would be the best choice.

but now i am lost as to how to handle the buttons. When i click on one selection from the search, it will deselect when i choose have or want on another game.

I understand that i should be creating a separately name form for each search result, but then how would i manage the data when sending it to my controller? Maybe i need incrementing form names and then count how many results and use that in my controller?

Also, i need the gameID associated with the selections so i need to send a hidden value with that data for each selection

maybe i am going about this the wrong way...

heres my code

```
echo '<div id="UserSearchGameResults">';
            echo '<form action="#" method="Post">';
            $x = 0;
            while($gamesLike != null)
            {
                $x++;

                echo '<div id="game_search_list_item">'.$x.'. '.$gamesLike['title'].'</div>

                <span class="gamelistblue">
                    <input type="radio" name="haveOrWant" value="have" />Have it
                </span>

                <span class="gamelistorange">
                    <input type="radio" name="haveOrWant" value="want" />Want it
                </span>

                <input type="hidden" name="gameID" value="'.$gamesLike['ID'].'" />';

                $gamesLike = $statement->fetch();
            }
            $statement->closeCursor();

            echo '<br /> <input type="submit" value="Add Game(s)" />';

            echo '</div></form>';
```

any help is appreciated with the subject

new ideas on how to handle my needs are welcome too.

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrays for the input names. Something like

```
<input type="radio" name="game' . $gamesLike['ID'] . '[haveOrWant]" value="have" />Have it
```